# Using Angular, how to display validation issues on an event?

Tags: angularjs

I do not want to render validation issues until a user attempts to submit my form.

I have a form with 2 fields, one is `required` and `ng-minlength=5`, the other is `ng-minlength=5`. If the fields are invalid, I would like to display them with a red background if the user attempts to submit the form.

I am attempting to do this by determining the style in the controller based on the field's validity and if the submit button has been clicked.

This isn't working for me though, the field never displays as red. Any suggestions as to how I can get this approach to work?

Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a strategy more idiomatic to Angular?

https://jsfiddle.net/dk89dhp2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
.my_invalid{
   border-color:#ffdddd;
   background-color:#ffdddd;
   background-image: none;
  }

</style>

<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <form name="myFormNg">
        <input type="text" class="myForm.getFormFieldCssClass(myFormNg.id)" name="id" ng-model="myForm.id" ng-minlength="5" required> Id <br/>
        <input type="text" class="myForm.getFormFieldCssClass(myFormNg.name)" name="name" ng-model="myForm.name" ng-minlength="5"> Name <br/>
        <button type="button" ng-click="myForm.submit()">Submit</button>
    </form>

<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
                $scope.myForm = {};
                $scope.showErrors = false;

                $scope.myForm.submit = function() {
                        $scope.showErrors = true;
                }

                $scope.myForm.getFormFieldCssClass = function(ngModelController) {
                    if (ngModelController.$pristine) 
                        return "";
                    return ngModelController.$valid && $scope.showErrors ? "" : "my_invalid";
                    // additional logic to check if empty and required?
                }
            } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now it's not working because you're using `class` that allow you to bind only "static" classes instead of the ng-class directive.

i'd change your code just to add the directive, about your approach, i'd stick with it, you need some sort of control that check if the form is valid and if the error are enabled.

```
<input type="text" ng-class="{'input1Error': myForm.getFormFieldCssClass(myFormNg.id})" />
<input type="text" ng-class="{'input2Error': myForm.getFormFieldCssClass(myFormNg.id})" />
```

then at the end of your method change the return type to boolean to determine whether to apply or not the class

```
$scope.myForm.getFormFieldCssClass = function(ngModelController) {
   if (ngModelController.$pristine) 
      return false;
   return ngModelController.$invalid && $scope.showErrors ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works for me. when I click submit, the fields turn red after I modify them or change focus. any suggestion for how I can update their ng-class on submit click?

Comment: you're welcome. well actually now the field should modify their classes only if you submit the form. what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Nevermind, I think this line was causing the style not to update as expected. works better after I removed it: `if (ngModelController.$pristine) 
      return false;`

Answer (score 0):

you can try as below also.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.my_invalid{
   border-color:#ffdddd;
   background-color:#ffdddd;
   background-image: none;
  }
  </style>
<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <form name="myFormNg">
        <input type="text" class="myForm.getFormFieldCssClass(myFormNg.id)" id="textbox1" name="id" ng-model="myForm.id" ng-minlength="5" required> Id <br/>
        <input type="text" class="myForm.getFormFieldCssClass(myFormNg.name)" id="textbox2" name="name" ng-model="myForm.name" ng-minlength="5"> Name <br/>
        <button type="button" ng-click="myForm.submit()">Submit</button>
    </form>

<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
                $scope.myForm = {};
                $scope.showErrors = false;
                
                $scope.myForm.submit = function() {
                 angular.element('#textbox1').css('border-color', 'red');
     angular.element('#textbox2').css('border-color', 'red');
     
      
                }
               
                $scope.myForm.getFormFieldCssClass = function(ngModelController) {
                    if (ngModelController.$pristine) 
                     return "";
                    return ngModelController.$valid && $scope.showErrors ? "" : "my_invalid";
                    // additional logic to check if empty and required?
                }
            } );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```